# elastic beanstalk 403 php server htaccess

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm just trying to set up a simple php server and run my application. I keep on getting a 403 forbidden error after uploading my application though.

It works fine on my localhost and namecheap server. So I must have the aws server config messed up.

I have an htaccess file, I'm not sure if I can upload that into eb

I switched the software config to my root folder as well.

Haven't a clue how elastic beanstalk works, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem.

When compressing your project and uploading to elastic beanstalk you need to set your folder as the root folder.

1. Click on your app
2. Go to Configuration
3. Click Software Configuration
4. Go to Document root and type the name of your folder with a slash before and after
   e.g. `/nameOfFolder/`
5. Apply and you're done